# Want to show create time for some files.

Tags: linux, perl, ctime

I was writing perl and run it in window system pretty good . 
But when i transfer the perl script from windows system to Linux. 
And run in Linux system , i get wrong date/time. 
Need some help. Thanks.

The source code in Perl

```
   if (($file =~ m/(\d)(\S+)\.csv/) && ($flag == 0))  
            {
                    open(para_file,$file);
                    $datetime_string = ctime( stat($file)->ctime );

                    while ($line=<para_file>)
                    {
                    if ($line =~ /0\,170\,16\,/) 
                            {
                                    $cal = $cal + 1;
                            }
                    }
                            push(@data,"$cal");
                            push(@data,"$datetime_string");
             }
```

$file will be my file name. The windows date & time on create are correct but don't understand why in LINUX it give me the wrong date & time.

Output of generation , from windows

9023-0    50000   5111   10.22          **Mon Jul 21 17:44:38 2014**
 9023-2    100000  23251  23.25          **Fri Apr 11 10:12:19 2014**
 9024_AHG            5000           0              0.00           **Thu Nov 27 15:28:55 2014**

Output of generation , from linux

9023-0    50000   5111   10.22          **Thu Jul 30 16:45:25 2015**
 9023-2    100000  23251  23.25          **Thu Jul 30 16:45:25 2015**
 9024_AHG            5000           0              0.00           **Thu Jul 30 16:45:25 2015**

Comment: How are the file systems accessed on different systems? Obviously you must have some sort of file server you use, or is that a removable drive?

Comment: If you transferred the files to Linux from Windows their creation time will change and will show the time they were moved.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Strictly speaking that would _not_ be a move, but a copy. You cannot _move_ a file between systems. That is why actually a new file gets created which explains the new creation time. A real _move_ would actually preserve the time.

Comment: @arkascha: Ah I see.

Comment: the file was in windows. i run the perl in linux by ctime. without transfering the file to linux

Comment: the file was at window and i run the script in both linux and window. windows give me the correct date/time but linux not correct. is there something to do with perl version i am using?

Comment: I repeat my question from above: if you run the script on different systems, then how can they access the same file? By what means?

Comment: i create a path in linux which will link to window share folder. but the bridge was create by others ppl. is that need to find out how it was access?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here isn't what you're doing, it's that you misunderstand what `ctime` is. Linux filesystems record a *change* time not a *creation* time.

`mtime` denotes modification of file content. `ctime` denotes modification of attributes. As a result, they may well be the same number.

However what you *cannot* get is "create time" because the EXT filesystem doesn't record it. (Other filesystem formats may - NTFS for example - but I'm not sure I'd suggest using NTFS on a Linux box!)

Comment: how to do with NTFS on Linux?

Comment: @cs87 that is a question that you should probably post either on SuperUser or Unix/Linux.

Comment: But seriously - don't, it's nasty. Just accept that creation time isn't that interesting or meaningful. Changing your whole filesystem just to get create times is a lot of pain for negligible benefit.